# Swingworker not running doInBackground() method

Tags: java, swingworker

I have a jtextfield where I input part of a computer name in and when I click search, it gives me the full computer name. My issue is that the full computer name is supposed to output to a jLabel, but it only outputs if I run another instance of the GUI. I know I have to use Swingworker to get it to output on (Search Button) button click, but it never outputs within the same instance. Any help is appreciated.

I don't want to miss anything out of the code I'm listing so here's the full class I'm trying to use SwingWorker with. The doInBackground() method is at the bottom of the class. The jLabel I'm trying to output the computer name to is called "testLabel"

```
 final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CN=([^,]+).*");
            try {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] tokens = PATTERN.split(","); //This will return you a array, containing the string array splitted by what you write inside it.
                    //should be in your case the split, since they are seperated by ","
                   // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    CN = sCurrentLine.split("CN=",-1)[1].split(",",-1)[0];

                    System.out.println(CN);
                   testLabel.setText(CN);
                }


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateCN());
```

Code at bottom of class

```
private Runnable updateCN() {
         testLabel.setText("Test afterwards");
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any updates to the GUI should be performed in the Event Dispatching Thread. And `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` performs a task in a background thread (non EDT). So you seem to have mixed it up.

To fix it, always perform your setText in a EDT thread by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`. If you want to do a long running process which doesn't update the GUI from EDT, then use `SwingWorker.doInBackground()`.

Also, the `doInBackground()` method is called only when you invoke `SwingWorker.execute()` which you don't seem to have done anywhere in your code.

Comment: I tried implementing invokeLater, but it doesn't work properly. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. I updated the code above to reflect the changes. Any Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work properly_?? Also, note that `invokeLater()` doesn't get invoked until all the pending updates are completed on the EDT thread.. So, atleast for debugging you can use `invokeAndWait()` instead... Also, make sure you are not already in the EDT.. Normally the thread from which you create the Frame becomes the EDT by default...

Comment: I made the necessary changes based on what I could find on invokelater, but I'm getting a null pointer exception. Any ideas why? See updated code above.